# Drop row by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm creating the following dataframe:

I'm trying to drop the row where the value of Distance from UAV is the smallest, like the condition as shown below.

```py
    def append_distance_and_pd_table(self):
        distance_list = [get_distances(item, uav) for item in self.d]
        df = pd.DataFrame(data=self.d, columns=['Latitude', 'Longitude'])
        df['Distance from UAV'] = distance_list

        print(df)

        df.drop(df['Distance from UAV'].min())

        print(df)
```

The output of this code is:

```
    Latitude  Longitude  Distance from UAV
0  33.138223  35.286738           2.767079
1  33.038223  35.286738           9.408624
2  33.088223  35.336738           4.509696
3  33.088223  35.236738           7.609565


raise KeyError("{} not found in axis".format(labels[mask]))

KeyError: '[2.767079] not found in axis'
```

Comment: provide necessary information in your question like sample data, logic behind your function and relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For df like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = (pd.DataFrame({'TC': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Distance from UAV': [2.767079,9.408624,4.509696,7.609565]}))

   TC  Distance from UAV
0   1           2.767079
1   2           9.408624
2   3           4.509696
3   4           7.609565
```

Find row index with min value, then drop.

```
min_row_index = df[df['Distance from UAV'] == df['Distance from UAV'].min()].index[0]
df = df.drop(min_row_index)
```

Output:

```
   TC  Distance from UAV
1   2           9.408624
2   3           4.509696
3   4           7.609565
```